# How to go to my current location using the custom button on react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, expo

When the user goes to another view of map, and wants to go back to his current location, I have created a custom button. When the user clicks the button, it should go back to his current location.

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import MapView, {Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet, Image , Text, View} from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { 
  LocationView ,
  LocationBtn,
  } from '../components/styles';
  import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


  
const Map = (props) =>{


  
     const [mapRegion, setMapRegion] = useState(null);
     useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
            return;
          }
    
          let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
          setMapRegion({
              longitude: location.coords.longitude,
              latitude: location.coords.latitude,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0421
            });
            console.log('location', location)
        })();
      }, [])

     

    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
        region={mapRegion}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        mapType={props.mapType}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        loadingEnabled={true}
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
        userInterfaceStyle='light'
        showsTraffic={true}
        >
           <Marker 
          coordinate={mapRegion}
          >
            <Image source={require('../assets/marker.png')} style={{height: 90, width: 90}} />
          </Marker>
        </MapView>
         <LocationView>
           <LocationBtn 
           >
                <MaterialIcons 
                name="my-location" 
                size={30}
                 color="black"
                  style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 13}}
                  />
                </LocationBtn>
             </LocationView>  
        </View>
         
       
    )
} 


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
        height: '100%', 
    },
})


export default Map;
```

My idea was to put `onPress(mapRegion)` in the `<LocationBtn></LocationBtn/>`(which is the custom button), and when the user clicks the button, it goes to the user current location which is in the `mapReagion` state
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in react-native-map to go to your current location. You need to implement on your own.

Use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location to get your location (you can do lot more) add a marker on the map using react-native-map functions.

Comment: The idea is when the user scrolls to another side of the map and wants to get back to his current location, he will press the button and go back to his location. So I have thought in the ```<LocationBtn />``` to put an ```onPress()```.  Not sure if that logic is correctt